# Flash, AS3 drag movieclip based on full size, not what's inside

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, draggable

First post here, I have tried searching but couldn't find what I'm looking for but most people seem to get the answers they're after!

I'm working on some draggable/droppable functionality in flash as3, but the issue I have at the moment, is that I can only drag on what's inside the draggable movieclip, not the whole of the movieclip itself. For instance, say I have a stick man, I can only drag him if I select the lines, not the whole size of the movieclip

i.e if the arms extend outwards by x amount I should be able to click upto x width, down by the legs on whitespace (within the confines of the movie clip bounding box) and still be able to drag.

Is this possible?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a Shape inside the movieclip with alpha=0 for the area you want to be clickable as well.

If mc is your movieclip and you want a rectangular clickable area and your stickman is not to the left of x= 0 and not furhter up than y=0:

```
var shape : Shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0);
shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, mc.width, mc.height);
mc.addChild(shape);
```

If you are using the flash IDE you can alwo just draw any kind of graphic within the movie clip with a colour with alpha value of 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response, worked a charm. If I later had something that resized the original mc, I take it I would need to resize the shape within, or would that resize as well?

Comment: If you reisize the whole mc, it resizes all content as well, so there's no need to adjust the clickable area. You only need to adjust it whenever you want change within the movieclip.